# is it possible to run sails & nuxt on a single express instance?

Tags: express, sails.js, nuxt.js

I understand that the intended setup is.
Seperate backend server (e.g. Sails, Laravel, ...)
plus frontend server with nuxt.js or prerendered static content generated with nuxt and statically hosted (e.g. AWS S3, now, ...)

I am wondering if it is also possible to run sails and nuxt within the same node/express instance.

Answer (score 1):

Nuxt.js can be used as a middleware so i think you can. Check the docs: [Using nuxt.js programmatically](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js#using-nuxtjs-programmatically)